# hadoop cluster not using all the memory provided,just using 24 gb out of 72gb?

Tags: hadoop, memory, hive, hdfs, azure-resource-manager

I am using a 3 node hadoop cluster.
Node 1: 32GB RAM,
Node 2: 32GB RAM,
Node 3: 8GB RAM

while running a job its only using 24gb, 8 gb for each node.
Containers used 24.
Vcores used 24.
It should use all the memory provided i.e total 72gb.
Can anyone help me out with the solution.